# How to quantitatively measure work done by a biological system?

Tags: biophysics, thermodynamics

Thermodynamic efficiency can be expressed as the ratio of Work done(W) to Energy invested (Q).

```
Thermodynamic efficiency= W/Q
```

How can one measure work done by a biological system?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `W/Q`? If `Q/W` then "thermodynamic efficiency" is very high when you do little work but put in a lot of energy. Doesn't seem very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measuring the work done by a biological system seems pretty impossible. Imagine how many different ways one cell of your body uses energy (ATP). You can't really measure all the work done by every cell on a macro scale. Metabolic efficiency has been defined as... "[health](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health)". That seems just a little ambiguous. That's why we use things like averages to determine if energy use is normal or not, such as in [metabolic age](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolic_age).

In short, work is a more tangible term in discrete physics examples, but there is so much complicated energy use in biological systems that total systemic work can't be easily defined.

Answer (score 0):

Just like with work in non biological systems, one needs to consider the **path** that the system takes. The definition of work for a process depends on a path. As well, different types of potential energy can be equilibrated for different systems.

So what's your system? Let's say a plant is in a sealed system, with a movable piston. It starts with a small amount of CO2 gas and a lot dissolved in solution. Then the plant is placed in a light source, which can enter the closed system and drive photosynthesis. As the plant makes oxygen it comes out of solution and increases the volume/pressure of gas in the system. As a result, the photosynthesis could do work against the piston. Then, since the energy inputted from the light source can also be readily estimated, the thermodynamic efficiency of "driving a cylinder using photosynthetically derived oxygen gas."